# Unable to see few records in Lead related list in Account

Tags: page-layout, related-list

We have few accounts in which all the Leads are not visible in the related list. I have checked the access and I am able to access the account and lead independently. The Account lookup field on lead also looks correct, referring to the same account. There is no other account with similar name.

What could be the reason behind this behavior? Few leads are visible and few are not, does this imply any filter? But I am unable to find any configuration like that. Please help.

Comment: Filters, object permissions and view restrictions (visible only to me e.t.c) are the only reasons why a subset of your full data set would not be available to view in list view. Pagination is available be default, make sure you have not missed the "next page" option.

Comment: There are no filters applied. Object permissions are fine and there are no view restrictions as I am able to see the account and lead separately.